# Http creates session value on each request in php

Tags: php, csrf-protection

I've created csrf_token and stored in session variable. while the form submission checked post variable with the session variable. It works perfectly in HTTPS but not in HTTP **incognito window**.

I just figure out this problem it's because of session value is varying each time on the HTTP request.

give me suggestion to solve this issue. Thanks!

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['csrf_token'])) {
        $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = md5(uniqid());

}

if(isset($_POST['token']))
{
if (($_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['csrf_token'])) {
     echo "match";
}
else{
     echo "mismatch";
}
}
```

Comment: I would check the client first. On those calls where a new session has been wrongfully created, was the session cookie sent to the server in the request?

Comment: I didn't use cookie anywhere. I've only maintained in session

Comment: The session works because it sets a cookie on the client, usually called (if I recall correctly) `phpsessid`. If a client has a valid session cookie, the request will have access to that session, otherwise a new one will be created by `session_start()`. If the browser disables cookies the session won't persist between requests.

Comment: how to fix this? do I have to modify anything?

Comment: @Rad80 I got a temporary solution just redirected to HTTPS